# How to make lists according to the sequence by looping

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Convert

```
mylist = [['Taiwan', 'Japan', 'Korea'], [18, 30, 20], ['False', 'True', 'False'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

To

```
newlist = [['Taiwan', 18, 'False', 1], ['Japan', 30, 'True', 'False', 2], ['Korea', 20, 'False', 3]]
```

I tried to use  a `for` to solve it:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    for j in mylist:
        print(j[i])
```

But I didnt get the expected result:

```
Taiwan
```

I don't know how to do? Please help.

Comment: See how to use zip

Comment: `print([list(i) for i in zip(*mylist)])` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use zip for that:

```
mylist = [list(i) for i in zip(*mylist)]
```

mylist:

```
[['Taiwan', 18, 'False', 1], ['Japan', 30, 'True', 2], ['Korea', 20, 'False', 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one-liner:

```
>>> [[item[j] for item in mylist] for j in range(len(mylist[0]))]
[['Taiwan', 18, 'False', 1],
 ['Japan', 30, 'True', 2],
 ['Korea', 20, 'False', 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)!

```py
>>> list(zip(*mylist))
[('Taiwan', 18, 'False', 1), ('Japan', 30, 'True', 2), ('Korea', 20, 'False', 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip  for this

```
zip(*mylist)
```

and it gives list of set

for list of lit use,

```
[list(i) for i in zip(*mylist)]
```